# removing elements from xml with php - unorthodox xml

Tags: php, iphone, ios, xml

I created an ios app that parses an xml document. If a user logs in, their information will be added to the xml file. I would like to be able to remove a user if they are logging out or cancelling their logins. Essentially, I need to figure out how to delete an xml object (a bartender, in this case) that looks like this:

```
<Bars>
    <Bar>
        <bar_id>0</bar_id>
        <Bartenders>
            <Bartender>
                <imageURL>unique URL</imageURL>
                <shift>20:30</shift>
            </Bartender>
        </Bartenders>
    </Bar>
    <Bar>
        <bar_id>1</bar_id>
        <Bartenders>
               <Bartender>
                      <imageURL>aURL</imageURL>
                      <shift>a shift</shift>
                </Bartender>
                <Bartender>
                          <imageURL>aURL</imageURL>
                          <shift>a shift</shift>
                </Bartender>
        </Bartenders>
    </Bar>
```

For example, I want to remove a user based on a unique imageURL... I will also know the bar_id. This is the php that I have so far, but I am completely open to suggestions on doing it a different way

```
    $newimageURL = $row['imageURL'];
    $newBar_ID = $row['Bar_ID'];

    $xmlUrl = "Bars.xml"; // XML 
    $xmlStr = file_get_contents($xmlUrl);
    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlStr);
    $bartenders = $xml->xpath('//Bartenders');

         // something needs to happen here to remove the child

    $xml->asXML('Bars.xml');
```

I was told that I could use something of this sort:

```
$bartenders->removeChild($bartenders[$newBar_ID]);
```

Or xpath but I am not sure how to get the path right to the correct bartender with just the unique imageXML. I know I should have planned/designed this better, but I am crunched for time and this will have to do.

Sorry I am so bad with php...
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

There is a very nice script at http://php.net/manual/fr/ref.simplexml.php that works perfectly fine

```
function removeNode($xml, $path, $multi='one')
{
   $result = $xml->xpath($path);

      # for wrong $path
      if (!isset($result[0])) return false;

      switch ($multi) {
          case 'all':
                $errlevel = error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_WARNING);
                foreach ($result as $r) unset ($r[0]);
                error_reporting($errlevel);
                return true;

            case 'child':
               unset($result[0][0]);
               return true;

            case 'one':
               if (count($result[0]->children())==0 && count($result)==1) {
                   unset($result[0][0]);
                   return true;
               }

            default:
                  return false;             
      }
```

}

Please click on the link for more information

Comment: How will the xpath know which group of bartenders to go to?

Comment: `bar_id` is different for each bar and also `imageURL` is unique as you stated